# Reference Request: Primer on Relationship Economic Growth and Science / Technology

Tags: reference-request, economic-growth, technology, technological-progress

I'm in the early stages of planning a research agenda in this area, which means studying the current literature with an eye for further research opportunities.

[The Economics of Science and Technology, Audretsch et al](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1023/A:1014382532639) (2002) is one paper which I've found to be valuable.

What are some essential readings on and related to this topic?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endogenous_growth_theory